# How build gitlab as an image file to run with docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ce

I want to build `gitlab` as an image in order to run with docker because I can not pull in with this command:

```
docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

so I want to download it first, then build and finally run it with docker. Where I can find gitlab with ability to build with docker?

Comment: What is wrong with docker pull in your case?

Comment: during pull process it fails due to network problems so I decided to download  gitlab with ability to build with docker then run it @dvnguyen

Answer (score 0):

Here's the content of the latest gitlab's Dockerfile: https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/~/dockerfile/

Download it and use `docker build` to build your image.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the build process is also going out to the Internet to download stuff. The Docker build is really just downloading the gitlab `deb` file and installing it in a `ubuntu` bas image. If the question is actually looking to do an "offline" build then they would also need to download all the `deb` files required and modify the `Dockerfile` to install those instead of from public apt mirrors.